# Postgres SQL query grouped by gender. How to show values where a row does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, calendar, cross-join, not-exists

I have a query that counts total messages sent by day, and groups them by gender.

If on a day there were no messages sent to males, there will be no row for male.

How do I insert a count value of 0 for males in this case?

Query:

```
SELECT d.date dated, count(se.id), gender
FROM    (
        select to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date
        FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS offs
        ) d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, customer_id, client_report.insert_time, profile.gender, profile.house_income, profile.address AS postcode, profile.age AS age_group, profile.is_employed, profile.is_married, profile.no_children, profile.no_cars, profile.shopping_frequency
        FROM common.client_report
        JOIN common.profile
        ON client_report.profile_id = profile.uuid 
        WHERE sms_status = 'SUCCESS' 
        ) se
ON (d.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', se.insert_time), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
WHERE customer_id = 25::int AND d.date::date BETWEEN '2017-07-03'::date AND '2017-08-01'::date
GROUP BY d.date, gender
ORDER BY d.date ASC
```

I want the results to be consistent, such as:

```
    day, count, gender
    2017-07-01, 10, Female
    2017-07-01, 5, Male
    2017-07-02, 0, Female
    2017-07-02, 8, Male
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume you've made a table with `genders`:

```
CREATE TABLE genders
(
    gender text primary key
) ;

INSERT INTO genders (gender)
VALUES
   ('MALE'),
   ('FEMALE') ;
```

If you want all dates/genders in your answer, you need to make a `cross join` of all possible dates and genders, then `LEFT JOIN` it with the data that actually answers your question:

```
SELECT
    calendar.cal_date AS date, coalesce(gender_count, 0) AS gender_count, genders.gender
FROM
    -- Virtual table with all dates/genders
    genders
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
        generate_series(/*now()*/ date '2017-07-10' - interval '7 days' /* or '1 year' */, 
                        /*now()*/ date '2017-07-10', 
                        interval '1 day')::date AS cal_date
    ) AS calendar

    -- The table with the actual data
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        date, gender, count(gender) AS gender_count
    FROM
        client_report
        JOIN profile ON profile.uuid = client_report.profile_id
    WHERE
        -- conditions to actually select data
        customer_id = 25
        AND sms_status = 'SUCCESS'
    GROUP BY
        date, gender
    ) AS counts 
        ON counts.date = calendar.cal_date AND counts.gender = genders.gender
ORDER BY
    calendar.cal_date, genders.gender ;
```

You'll get an answer like:

```
date       | gender_count | gender
:--------- | -----------: | :-----
2017-07-03 |            1 | FEMALE
2017-07-03 |            2 | MALE  
2017-07-04 |            2 | FEMALE
2017-07-04 |            0 | MALE  
2017-07-05 |            0 | FEMALE
2017-07-05 |            0 | MALE  
2017-07-06 |            0 | FEMALE
2017-07-06 |            2 | MALE  
2017-07-07 |            2 | FEMALE
2017-07-07 |            0 | MALE  
2017-07-08 |            0 | FEMALE
2017-07-08 |            1 | MALE  
2017-07-09 |            0 | FEMALE
2017-07-09 |            0 | MALE  
2017-07-10 |            0 | FEMALE
2017-07-10 |            0 | MALE
```

Note that I haven't taken a full year, but just 8 days.

You can see the full example with sample data at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ff17d8fc38fbd90575022cf7571287f5)*

NOTE: I have ignored the *insert_date*, and concentrated only on the *date*, because I don't know which exact meaning each has. I think your point was *how to use a cross join*, the rest is not that relevant to the scenario.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN (VALUES('Male'), ('Female')) AS genders(gender)` is much more efficient. Why creating a temporary table if you can use CTE with values?..

Comment: @VaoTsun: I first put it, then took it out not to make the questioner concentrate on "what are those `VALUES` if this isn't an insert?". On the other hand, I don't assume the table *is* temporary. The 'MALE'/'FEMALE' is an oversimplification. Ask *cisgenders*, or *genderqueers*...

Comment: Even if this is method is more efficient, is there any way of doing this that does not explicitly define the the demographic values E.g. Male, Female. I am asking this because I have to apply this to different demographics, meaning different values, and I was creating this dynamically, where based on the users demographic choice it would use the same query. Would this be possible with another generate series?

Comment: Yeah, easy: change `genders` by `(SELECT DISTINCT gender FROM profile) AS gender`... or, in general `(SELECT DISTINCT whatever AS my_demographic_dimension FROM profile) AS demographic_dimension` and change accordingly.

Comment: Have you any idea about whether a query like this works well in pdo_pgsql drivers for DB connections (I think that's it's name, the pg_sql pdo driver that would come with Laravel and PHP). It's just I'm having terrible results with it in my application, but through pgAdmin it works just as I need it to

Comment: If you end up generating the same SQL sentence, performance should be the same. If the "layers" that Laravel adds changes things... that would be another storey.

Comment: I realised that I am using  version of the query more like the other answer here. I tried looking into the  laravel "layers" but to no avail. I've created a new question with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443179/laravel-db-select-statement-query-returns-column-name-as-result-rather-than-val
At this point I'm actually hoping its something stupid you can just point out straight away :P

Answer (score 1):

You should `cross join` list of dates with list of genders.

Something like:

```
SELECT d.date dated, count(se.id), d.gender
FROM    (
        select to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date, gender
        FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS offs
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES('Male'), ('Female')) AS genders(gender)
        ) d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, customer_id, client_report.insert_time, profile.gender, profile.house_income, profile.address AS postcode, profile.age AS age_group, profile.is_employed, profile.is_married, profile.no_children, profile.no_cars, profile.shopping_frequency
        FROM common.client_report
        JOIN common.profile
        ON client_report.profile_id = profile.uuid 
        WHERE sms_status = 'SUCCESS' 
        ) se
ON (d.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', se.insert_time), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND d.gender = se.gender
WHERE customer_id = 25::int AND d.date::date BETWEEN '2017-07-03'::date AND '2017-08-01'::date
GROUP BY d.date, d.gender
ORDER BY d.date ASC
```

Comment: Not working my end :( Looked into how a cross join works and didn't really think it would work? (no offense! I'm trying to understand what this would normally do). Trying to get my head round it as well, I need to count rows that don't exist on days as well as one that may not exists for a gender :S

Comment: Lukasz suggests first prepare each date against each gender matrix, to be outer joined later against your data - sounds very much reasonable, and probably would be the best solution. I'm not upvoting only because OP did not confirm it works

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, it helped a lot. Can confirm its acting as you think, it creates a male and female gender per date. And the reason it is not working is because of my WHERE customer_id = 25:int

Removed that WHERE and it works as expected

Comment: Very much!  And after staring at it for a few mins >.< it all made sense! Of course my WHERE clause broke it, it was saying WHERE value is 25 on the whole result, rather than within the actual data I want :D 
The only reason I am not accepting this as an answer is that joanolos answer is the same and provides a good description.